# AutoMapper ProjectTo and EF Core Value Conversion for enum stored as string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper

How can we have AutoMapper's `ProjectTo` work with EF Core's Value Conversion for an enum stored as a string?
The following code prints `0` instead of `Blue`

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using System;

await using var ctx = new MyDbContext(
    new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
    .UseSqlite("datasource=db.sqlite")
    .Options);
ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

ctx.House.Add(new House { Color = Color.Blue });
ctx.SaveChanges();

var config = new MapperConfiguration(_ => _.CreateMap<House, HouseDto>());
var house = ctx.House.ProjectTo<HouseDto>(config).Single();
Console.WriteLine(house.Color);

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<House> House { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<House>().Property(_ => _.Color).HasConversion<string>();
    }
}
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
public enum Color
{
    Blue = 1
}
public class HouseDto
{
    public ColorDto Color { get; set; }
}
public enum ColorDto
{
    Blue = 1
}
```

csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: For enumerations, these can be shared between the DTO and entity. If you are getting a value of "0" back, it's likely because Automapper is unable to convert the Color enum to a ColorDto enum. If both use the same Enum type it should work as expected. The string conversion for EF just tells EF to store "Blue" to the DB rather than "1".

Comment: You can drop the converter and just use `Map`. `ProjectTo` works with server evaluation.

Comment: You cannot use `ProjectTo` with properties that has conversion.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! It looks like `ProjectTo` and `HasConversion` won't work together based on the comments.